# Centered home page div with background picture

Tags: html, css

I want to create a home page that has a centered background image with 30px padding all round the image. Simple enough but impossible to achieve.

```
   <body>
    <div class="megawrapper">
      <div class="home-page">
       </div>
    </div>
   </body>

.megawrapper {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.home-page {    
    padding: 30px;
    background-image: url(images/street.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/geike/okyg5p2o/

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly you want. Does this help you: https://jsfiddle.net/okyg5p2o/4/

Comment: @Mojtaba lets use your code for example. The red is the 30px padding that goes round the grey center equally which means its the background color for megawrapper. The grey center contains the image 100%, which means the grey wont show. thaths what I want

Comment: @Mojtaba the 30px padding should be on all sides of "home-page" div and home-page div should be centered both horizontally and vertically within megawrapper

Comment: @Mojtaba, what happens when the `.home-page` content is taller than the device in your solution?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, that is not a solution. As I mentioned, I was not sure what he wants. I tried to give him an idea if I understood correct

Comment: @Joseph, I think you want something like this one: https://jsfiddle.net/okyg5p2o/5/ . By the way, as I do not have any image inside the inner div tag, I put a min-height o make it visible.

Comment: @mojtaba It's a technique I kept using for centering stuff, until I discovered has problems when child is bigger than parent, especially when parent is body. Just wanted to make sure you are aware of this. A happy new year!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, Happy new year to you too. By the way, I did some changes in my second sample code which always keeps the parent in full size

Comment: @Mojtaba In a discussion with someone else I was asked to demonstrate the bug described above. So [here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/337dsj5s/), in case you wanted to see it. Make result pane small enough to not fit all the text and you'll lose the top of the centered div.

Answer (score 2):

**Using border:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #333 url("http://www.descoperalocuri.ro/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Riga-o-imagine-clasic%C4%83-pentru-centrul-vechi-1024x575.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  border: 30px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

**Using padding:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.wrapper {
  background: url("http://www.descoperalocuri.ro/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Riga-o-imagine-clasic%C4%83-pentru-centrul-vechi-1024x575.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

**Using margin:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 30px;
  background: url("http://www.descoperalocuri.ro/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Riga-o-imagine-clasic%C4%83-pentru-centrul-vechi-1024x575.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

**My proposed solution (no wrappers):**

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  background: url("http://www.descoperalocuri.ro/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Riga-o-imagine-clasic%C4%83-pentru-centrul-vechi-1024x575.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
  background-clip: content-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* min-height: calc(100vh - 60px); */
  min-height: 200vh; /* this is here to see page scrolling. remove and uncomment previous line */
}
body::before {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 30px solid #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I made the body twice the height of viewport in this last one to show what would happen when contents extend above the fold.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Gheorghiu thats another way to do it. but cant i use padding instead of border?

Comment: It's possible. But first I need you to explain why. What difference does it make if the attribute used is called `border`, `padding` or `xpzyfrstqq` if the result is what you want? Programming is a bunch of `1`s and `0`s helping us get jobs done. What's the job here?

Comment: I added `padding` and `margin` based solutions. You still owe me an explanation on why does it have to be `padding`.

Comment: Regarding: "Simple enough but impossible to achieve": Web is virtual space, Joseph. Anything is possible. In web, "impossible" actually means "doing it wrong".

Comment: no real reason for wanting padding just something am used to but seemed not to be working today. Thanks for your solutions, exactly what I needed

Comment: can you tell if this website using javascript to maintain the divs centered? http://www.danielspatzek.com/home

Comment: It's using a modified version of [tiltfx.js](https://tympanus.net/Development/ImageTiltEffect/) and it's built using [webflow.js](https://help.webflow.com/). It's far from what I'd call "clean code".

Comment: Actually thats the effect I was trying to create with the padding. The tilitfx effect part of the background image is a centered div and it is surrounded by 60px padding, while its parent div has as its background the a fully stretched out image

Comment: is he using javasrcipt to center the divs

Comment: Nope: `.home-page {padding: 60px;}`. Javascript is used to apply inline style (mostly CSS transforms) in order to move them around.

Comment: @ Andrei Gheorghiu, I tried recreating body>megawrapper>home-page but I cant get .home-page to center with the 60px padding

Comment: @ Andrei Gheorghiu am using your last solution to center it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set background attributes for `megawrapper`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.megawrapper {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-640-480-9.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 30px 30px;
    background-size: calc(100% - 60px);
}
.home-page {
    padding: 60px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
    <div class="megawrapper">
      <div class="home-page"> 
      </div>
    </div>
```